# The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, enterprise-library

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 for c#
I have the following namespace on my code

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.AppSettings;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
```

and I keep on getting this error:

-The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What should I do?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650106.aspx

Comment: I had this same problema in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Turns out that cleaning, rebuilding and rebooting the OS (several times) did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a reference to the enterprise library from your project. You can download the dlls here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx

Comment: [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages?q=enterpriselibrary) is another option instead of downloading the assemblies.

Comment: Yes that would be my recommended solution as well, but there is no official VS2005 support for nuget as far as I know. Or is there?

Comment: Good point. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7558894/254973 there is a crazy way to piece something together. But it's probably more trouble that it's worth since it would create more external work in the event someone else needs to use the project. Assemblies it is!

Comment: Ah, I was no aware of Scotts article, good to know. You can always run nuget.exe outside the VS environment to get the files, but as you already mentioned: It's easier to just download the libs if you're running VS2005.

Comment: What version should I download?

Comment: What .net framework are you using? I would probably get the newest (6) one: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789

Comment: Did that work for you? In case it did, please mark to question as answered. Thx

Comment: But I would recommend to you to update your whole solution including Visual Studio and the .net Framework if that's possible. A lot of (good) things happend since .net 2.0...

Answer (score 4):

As well as referencing the DLLs from the project, also make sure that the Target Framework in the project properties are at least as high as the Microsoft Enterprise Library version:

- [Enterprise Library 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx) - .NET Framework 4.5 (so you [probably want Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010#12390581) - if you use 2010 / 4.0 you get the error [Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as#13750130))
- [Enterprise Library 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) - .NET Framework 3.5
- [Enterprise Library 4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647292.aspx) - .NET Framework 3.5

Also make sure it's *not* set to Client Profile (e.g. .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile) otherwise you will also get the same error.

As an aside, to download the Enterprise Library 6.0:

- run the self-extracting executable `EnterpriseLibrary6-binaries.exe`
- run download script in PowerShell:

  - start an Administrator command prompt
  - navigate to the directory containing `install-packages.ps1`
  - use the command `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File install-packages.ps1`

For 5.0, you can download the MSI and use [Universal Extractor](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=641) if you don't want to install the DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue is resolved for me when I changed my "Target Framework" from ".Net Framework  4 Client Profile' to '.Net Framework  4'.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2005 only supports raw .NET 2.0 projects.

You can see from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc467894.aspx) that right now only a few releases are active,

> - Enterprise Library 6 - April 2013
> - Enterprise Library 5.0 - April 2010
> - Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Windows Azure - November 2011
> - Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Silverlight - May 2011
> - Enterprise Library 4.1 - October 2008

Even for 4.1, [Visual Studio 2008 and above is required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649754.aspx).

The last release supporting Visual Studio is [the 3.1 release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647377.aspx) which is 6 years old.