# Visual Studio 2005 Support by PostSharp?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, postsharp, log4postsharp

My Application is running in visual studio 2005 .Net framework 2.0.Is Visual Studio 2005 Supported by Post Sharp? Nuget Manager package is not a part of visual studio 2005. Let know your input.

Thanks,
Kumar Manish

Comment: The [earliest version you can still get](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-15-SP1) was released in 2009, so I doubt it. But **you should be trying for yourself**. Using a 12 year old version and expecting support from a) vendors and b) the community is pushing it. Why don't you use the free edition of a later version of VS anyway?

Comment: See also [using NuGet with Visual Studio 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7555883/33499) and [Using Nuget in Visual Studio 2005 & 2008](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/Using-Nuget-in-Visual-Studio-2005-&-2008).

Answer (score 0):

No, PostSharp 5.0 supports .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and later along with Visual Studio 2012 Update 5 and later.

If the target machine is running .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or later it would be in theory possible to use PostSharp from command line (see [this](http://doc.postsharp.net/command-line)).